# Why using Link view prints to Debugger console: "[open] LAUNCH: Launch failure with -10652 ..."?

Tags: swiftui, hyperlink

I have a simple `Link` view:

```
Link("Help", destination: URL(string: "https://linkToMyAppHelpPage.xyz")!)
```

When I tap the `Link` in my app, I get this message in Xcode's Debugger console:

> [open] LAUNCH: Launch failure with -10652/ <FSNode 0x600002e51880> { isDir = y, path = '/Applications/Firefox.app' }

The given URL opens correctly in Firefox.

I don't understand what this message means. Is it just log noise or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If your app is functioning as intended and the link opens correctly, just ignore this messages. These messages are often internal implementation details that are not meant for end-users or app developers to be concerned with. I guess it tries to launch your default web browser firefox